# RSS feed in Android Application

Tags: javascript, php, html, rss, cpanel

I sincerely need help with my rss feed as I have no idea where to begin since the feeds are not from my database. It would be great to have guidance on how I retrieve the feeds in my application. I'm currently using visual studio 2016 for an android application.

Thank you.

Comment: where are they from?

Comment: Nobody can help you with vague concepts like *"help with my rss feed"*. Be a lot more specific. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: The feeds are from a url given by my client

Comment: you want to use those feeds on your application ?

Comment: yes.  They have given me permission to use it.